# Nashorn debugging API

Tags: javascript, java, debugging, nashorn

In our application we have some scripts in JS written by users of our application. We use Nashorn for executing it. And we need to provide some debugging opportunities: at least breakpoints and variables watch.

As far as I understand, Nashorn *has no* debugging API.
I know about debugging with Idea or NetBeans IDE, but it is not suitable for us. We need debugging features in our own user interface.

Is it possible to implement debugging features in Nashorn? May be [JPDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Debugger_Architecture) is only one way to achieve it?

Comment: Hi, did you get anywhere with this? Looking into this myself.

Answer (score 0):

JPDA is the way Netbeans debugger works with Nashorn.  There are some supplementary callbacks in Debugger.java used to assist stack frames